# Не видит высоту картинки из Firestore в CollectionView (PinterestLayout)

Tags: swift, firebase, url, uicollectionview

Есть проект с CollectionView(PinterestLayout), то есть высота cell зависит от высоты картинки не обрезая при этом ее по ширине, как тут: https://ibb.co/J3KdDtG, я пытаюсь сделать тоже самое в проекте где картинка берется из Firestore (то есть, это ссылка), картинку он видит,  но с размерами беда как тут: https://ibb.co/JzXZv3V, знаю что проблема скорее всего в этой части кода, не пойму что нужно делать, спасибо.

````
       {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
           cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: flovers[indexPath.row].floverImg!))
           cell.label.text = flovers[indexPath.row].floverName
         //  cell.descriptionLabel.text = flovers[indexPath.row].floverName
           cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15

          
           return cell
       }```

тут все ок, картинку он берет
а тут мне кажется проблема

```{
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForPhotoAt indexPath: IndexPath, with width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
       
       if let post = posts?[indexPath.item], let photo = post.floverImg {
           let boundingRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
           let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: photo.size(), insideRect: boundingRect)
          
           return CGFloat(rect.size.height)
       }
       
       return 0
   }```

return CGFloat(rect.size.height) не работает, сразу идет к return 0(ну и соответственно ничего не показывает, показывает когда меняю значение)
````

Comment: Значит `posts` или `photo` у Вас nil. Ну и так как это ссылки и используется sd_setImage, то сами картинки подгружаются позже, соответственно, как отдать размер того, что появится позже? Нужно больше информации как храните и что можете поменять.

Comment: Я это примерно понимаю, но не совсем понимаю как это сделать. Может быть я вам могу написать куда-нибудь и скинуть файлы?

Comment: Я бы хотела хорошо понять как это работает, если это возможно я взяла бы «урок» у вас, чтобы вы мне объяснили, не бесплатно конечно. Напишите, если есть такая возможность

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос минимальный проект в котором воспроизводится проблема. Лучше всего ссылкой на GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/Alinevpraline/TestFlowersFail